# Maven UnsupportedClassVersionError Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: maven

So I recently installed maven using homebrew. Seemed to be working fine. I got this error. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling maven. Now I can't even type mvn --version without getting this error.

I've double checked using
javac -version
and java -version.
I'm using 1.8.0_51.

That isn't the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maven doesn't use the javac on the path, but is uses the JAVA_HOME. Execute `mvn -v` to see which Java version is actually used by Maven.

Comment: check your environment variables for the value of JAVA_HOME, just execute `set`